# Is it possible to install adobe connect on shared hosting through cpanle?

Tags: cpanel, windows-server-2012, shared-hosting, adobe-connect

I've watched many tutorials which instructors thought how to install adobe connect on local windows server mostly in VMware. I guess I need vps to follow those instructions.

What I'm really looking for is how to install adobe connect on subdomain of my shared hosting which uses cpanel. Is it even possible?

If yes, is there any tutorial how to do?

Thanks

Comment: I'm still waiting to get a solution...

Answer (score 0):

No, Adobe Connect requires a dedicated Windows Server to run. I made dozens of Adobe Connect installations, I provide professional installation help, installation scenario depends on your usage requirements (concurrent users etc.) therefore you may need additional servers for your installation.

Current version requires virtual servers running on Vmware ESX, but I made installations on several other virtualization products with no problem.